# После array_unique ключи значений идут не по порядку

Tags: php, массивы

**есть массив**


array(5) { [0]=> "2020-06-12" [1]=> "2020-06-18" [2]=> "2020-06-12" [3]=> "2020-06-18" [4]=> "2020-11-06" }


**после array_unique** 


array(3) { [0]=> "2020-06-12" [1]=> "2020-06-18" [4]=>"2020-11-06" }


**Как сделать, чтобы результат был:**


array(3) { [0]=> "2020-06-12" [1]=> "2020-06-18" [2]=>"2020-11-06" }


**при условии, что массив может состоять более чем из 3 значений**

Comment: [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values)

Comment: array_values() сбросит индексы

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4df0b2cacf6ed3066131945335d2c36bc7683775

Comment: Спасибо большое!